# Codeigniter file upload displaying error

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Controller code

```
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/'.$random;
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 100;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('imageupload'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        }
        print_r($data);
```

HTML code:

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" name="formname" id="formname"  method="post" action="http://www.example.com/Property/post">
    <input type="file" class="default" id="imageupload1" name="imageupload[]">
</form>
```

Whenever I am uploading file it displaying warning is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Because you have given `imageupload[]` name means array in your input field

Comment: Are you working on multiple file uploads?

Comment: Yes I am working for multiple file upload

Comment: I think you should use in controller `imageupload[0]` or somethinig else. Without seeing your full code can't suggest solution properly.

Comment: Than how can I upload multiple file?

Comment: @RushabhShah using for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
      //place this code in your function for multiple image upload
   $data = array();
    if(!empty($_FILES['imageupload']['name']))
    {
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['imageupload']['name']);
          for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
            $_FILES['imageupload']['name'] = $_FILES['imageupload']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['imageupload']['type'] = $_FILES['imageupload']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['imageupload']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['imageupload']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['imageupload']['error'] = $_FILES['imageupload']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['imageupload']['size'] = $_FILES['imageupload']['size'][$i];

            $uploadPath = 'uploads/';
            $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('imageupload')){
                $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            }
        }

        if(!empty($uploadData)){
            //Insert file  into the database using your model 


        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your input name should be without brackets:

```
<input type="file" class="default" id="imageupload1" name="imageupload">
```

Comment: If you are guessing any answer you should use comment.

Comment: How can I upload multiple file at same time?